# Yii2 : Add ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attribute

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, database-migration

I am extending `yii\db\Migration` class to add a method `timestamps` which will speed up me creating migrations. It will add all timestamps I need in every migration I will create.

I have seen this functionality in Laravel and CakePHP frameworks and I'm curious why this is not available by default within Yii 2 Migration Tool.

I have tried the following:

```
namespace custom\db;

use \yii\db\Migration as YiiMigration;

class Migration extends YiiMigration
{
    public function timestamps($tableName)
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            $tableName,
            'created_at',
            $this->timestamp()->null()->defaultExpression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            $tableName,
            'updated_at',
            $this->timestamp()->null()
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            $tableName,
            'deleted_at',
            $this->timestamp()->null()->defaultExpression('NULL')
        );
    }
}
```

In my actual migration in `up` or `safeUp` method I do the following:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $this->createTable('test', [
        'id' => 'pk',
    ]);

    $this->timestamps('test');
}
```

When I run this, fields `created_at` and `deleted_at` get their types and default values as specified. `created_at` is nullable but it's default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `deleted_at` is nullable and it's default value is `NULL`.

Problem is with `updated_at` field. I do not know the way to set attributes to that field with Yii 2 migrations and I need to set: `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute, which will always change the value when the record is updated.

Now, this goes even further. When I was testing this functionality only with using `created_at` field and with following options, that field would always get the attribute `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
$this->addColumn(
    $tableName,
    'created_at',
    $this->timestamp()
);
```

And yes, the field is not nullable and it contains the attribute I need. And that still is not what I need because I need the field nullable, followed by that attribute.

And for the end, the worst part...

I have tried doing the following for the `updated_at`, hoping that it will follow what happend to `created_at`:

```
$this->addColumn(
    $tableName,
    'updated_at',
    $this->timestamp()
);
```

Now the default value in the table is: `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and it's not nullable.

What is happening here, I do not have any clue anymore.

What am I doing wrong here and how to do this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the default value explicitly using the `->defaultValue(null)` and then you need to use the `->append('ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` in the following way for the `$type` parameter,

```
$this->addColumn(
    $this->_table,
    'updated_at',
    $this->timestamp()->defaultValue(null)->append('ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
);
```

The above will show you the field in phpmyadmin like below

[image]

See these discussions
- https://github.com/bizley/yii2-migration/issues/6

Comment: Should not need to add ->append()? I automatically set ON UPDATE when using timestamp(), or is this because you are adding fields after creating the data table? My code:`'update_time' => $this->timestamp()->notNull()->comment('更新时间')`, In database:`update_time           timestamp           default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP comment '更新时间'`

Comment: Another way is to use `defaultExpression()`

Comment: @PrabowoMurti thats for the `default` value means insert, and not on update.